# Cannot to upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

I have a PC with Ubuntu Studio 18.04.4.

Since 4 or 5 days ago, I can see a message: "You can upgrade to the last 20.04 version".

But, When I click on the button, Nothing happens!

There are not error meesages. There are not some special screen or panel. There is no action at all!

I tried with: `sudo apt full-upgrade`, `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Nothing!

What's wrong here?

How can I do to upgrade that PC?

Comment: Run `do-release-upgrade` and see what happens.

Comment: FYI:  The `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` should have updated you to 18.04.5 (the latest *bionic* release) which should be done first anyway), but won't *release-upgrade* you to the next release.

Comment: I will test both ideas. Be in tune.

Comment: I tested both ideas and the system asked me to perform all the available upgrades to my today version 18.04.1. I guess there is some delay in the Chilean server to the last 18.04.5 version. Of course, if somebody knows some way to get this last upgrade, please... Let me know!